# Preencher um Select Multiple e Fazer Update na Tabela

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Tenho um `<select multiple>` que é preenchido com informações de uma tabela **exames**, o usuário seleciona os exames que quer para uma determinada função e envia para cadastro na tabela **funcao_exames**, ok.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Como fazer para mostrar esses dados recuperados em uma tela de edição, ou seja, deixar como selecionado os exames que estão cadastrados para a função selecionada.
- Como fazer um update nessa tabela **funcao_exames**? Deletando os exames cadastrados daquela função e inserindo os novos?

**Tabela exames:** *id, nome, descricao*

**Tabela funcao:** *id, nome, descricao*

**Tabela funcao_exames:** *id, id_exame, id_funcao*

```
<select multiple id="exames" name="exames[]" class="form-control">
     @foreach($exames as $exame)
     <option value="{{ $exame->id }}">{{ $exame->nome }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

A maneira mais rápida de fazer isso é:

- Mostre todos o exames em checkboxes;

Faça um loop da mesma forma que está fazendo agora (só que com checkboxes), mas verifique em cada iteração do loop se o ID está presente na tabela funcao_exames (um select normal) e, se estiver, coloque o checkbox como CHECKED, se não, não.

Assim está resolvido seu primeiro problema: Como mostrar os exames já selecionados e permitir que o usuário desista ou escolha novos exames.

- Delete todos os registros da tabela funcao_exames e cadastre os exames que o usuário selecionou.

Quando o usuário clicar no botão "Salvar" (ou algo assim), delete todos os registros da tabela funcao_exames que tenham o id da função que o usuário está mexendo. Após isso, faça um loop e vá cadastrando todos os exames que o usuário selecionou.

Assim está resolvido seu último problema: Como atualizar a tabela deletando e inserindo exames.

Uma dica para a tela de edição: Coloque os checkboxes em uma tabela com estilo legal e use uma div com barra de rolagem, caso sejam muitos registros.